# Android assembleRelease Failed with Error: Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-4.0

- Android Studio 4.0.1
- gradle-wrapper.properties: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
- build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"
    
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

When assembling the release apk, it fails with an error:

> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't
> read
> [C:\Users\derek_y\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar]
> (Can't process class [android/annotation/Nullable.class] (Unsupported
> class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)))
> :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Why is android-30\android.jar requiring Java version 53.0 (Java 9)? Android Studio 4.0.1 is not supporting Java 9 right?

P.S.
I tried

- gradle-wrapper.properties: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
- build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

But then running the compiled apk triggered another error which is from a third-party SDK:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class a.b.c because it failed compile-time verification
```

I want a quick fix, and requesting the third-party to update takes time, so this is not helping at this moment. Or anyone could explain why this VerifyError occur and how to fix it?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue in the Android Gradle Plugin ([issue 77587908](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77587908)). It was fixed in AGP 3.3.0.

Try upgrading AGP to 3.3.0 instead of 4.0.1:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0"
```

This might be enough to fix your problem without introducing additional issues.